# Android Keystore for using HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, https, keystore

I have a web service in which I need to access through my Android application using HTTPS. I've brought and setup an SSL certificate from GoDaddy on my web server and I'm currently following this tutorial http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html to enable my application to work with my SSL certificate as by default, it is not allowing me to (Made a Https GET request, failed because it didn't trust the certificate).

I'm stuck at the part where it's asking me to create a 'keystore'. I've been reading the Android documentation and it hints that the keystore is supposed to be used for creating a certificate for the Android application itself (nothing to do with the certificate from my web-server).

Can anyone point me in the right direction with regards to setting up a 'keystore' for my web-server, allowing my application to use my SSL certificate for retrieving HTTPS content.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Here is a pastebin link to the code: http://pastebin.com/4ziApUGL, hope this helps. The class is used for asynchronously HTTP GET'ing content from a specified URL. In my case, it would be a HTTPS resource, which is causing the problem. I.e. I've tried it using normal HTTP and it works fine. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to follow that tutorial if your using a self-signed certificate on your website.

You also don't create a keystore on Android, it already comes with one populated with the "trusted" Certificate authorities' keys.  I couldn't get a list of the keys already in the keystore on my old Android 2.2 phone, but by 4.1 you can:

```
Settings -> Security -> Trusted credentials
```

So which of GoDaddy's [certificates](https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki) was you're website's certificate signed by?  Have you checked that you've installed the certificate correctly on your website?  View the websites certificate and look at the details and check that the certificate served by your website has been signed by a GoDaddy certificate that is in your Android device's list of trusted credentials.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Yes, the certificate is correctly installed on the website (denoted by the green https symbol). The certificate I used was gd_bundle.crt (GoDaddy certificate bundle) which has been setup correctly (done all of the Apache vhost configuration). It doesn't appear on the list of credentials on my Android device therefore would the gd_bundle.crt need to be manually copied over to it? If so, what about other users with other devices that may want to use the Application? Can you somehow embed the certificates in an Android application? Many Thanks.

Comment: The certificate you got from goDaddy that you installed on your website (gd_bundle.crt I assume) won't be in Android's keystore, but the certificate the GoDaddy signed it with should be.  The fact that your browser marks the certificate green does suggest that it should be.  As I said before, importing certificates is only necessary for self-signed, as yours is not self-signed then you shouldn't need to do that.I created my own certificate authority (CA) and used it to sign two of my personal websites' certificates.  Importing the CA into the Android keystore allowed the device to work.

Comment: You need to check that the CA on your website's certificate is one that is registered with your Android device.  If your browser is chrome click on the green certificate marker, then on "Cerficate Information" button, and then the "Details" tab.  Use the certificate at https://certs.godaddy.com/anonymous/repository.pki to check that you website's certificate looks similar.

Comment: If you import your site's certificate then anyone that installs your app from the playstore won't be able to connect to your server.  You will have to programmaticly install your websites certificate in your app (that's possible so I've read) - a waste of money then getting one signed by GoDaddy.  Going with a properly signed website certificate doesn't require that and is the better way.

Comment: Just noticed that gd_bundle.crt is one of GoDaddy's published keys.  And it looks like it is signed with GoDaddy's Class 2 CA key: `openssl x509 -in gd_bundle.crt -noout -text`.  That key is in the Android 4.1.1 keystore - I don't know about earlier version, but I would think it is.